# Using the search bar i want to display only the items that belong to the current user so what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to see the items that belong to the current user. In the Idex I'm using a GET method to display the products that belong to the current user but when I try to search an item, it displays me all the items, even the ones that dont belong to the current user. So where is the mistake?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var userProducts = db.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == currentUserId).ToList();
            return View(userProducts);

        }
    
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTxt)
                {
                    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    var userProducts = db.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == currentUserId);
                    if (searchTxt != null)
                    {
                        userProducts = db.Products.Where(x => x.Denumire.Contains(searchTxt));
                    }
                    return View(userProducts.ToList());
                }
```

Comment: you don't use `userProducts` in your second query, you search the entire `Products` table for the `searchText`. This is why you get results that are even not from the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to combine the two linq-statements:

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var userProducts = db.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == currentUserId);
if (searchTxt != null && userProducts.Any())
{
    // use the previous filtered products here
    userProducts = userProducts.Where(x => x.Denumire.Contains(searchTxt));
}
return View(userProducts.ToList());
```